# Pandas rolling function that discontinues itself

Tags: python

I am trying to find the rolling max of a column. However, I'd like to break and repeat after a window is completed. How can I do that?

Comment: `.rolling(window).max()` is not what are you looking for?

Comment: Indeed, but I do not want it to discontinue and re-continue after the window is complete @ilovebees

Comment: Therefore, suppose you have a window of 5. If I get it right, you want for all the first 5 rows the same max, and then the same logic applied for all the df? If it is not what you expect, plese provide a minimal example